# How do I get the size of text at a specified index of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, spanned

I'm using a `TextView` that has a `Spannable` object as the text and has multiple different text sizes. I want to know how do I get the text size at a specified index. If I use the `TextView.getPaint()` and get the text size from there, it always uses the "default" size, which is just the text size that the textview is set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I used this code:

```
Spanned span = (Spanned) getText();
RelativeSizeSpan[] sizeSpans = span.getSpans( charStart, charEnd, RelativeSizeSpan.class );
```

If this array is not null, it gives a scalar from the default text size by calling `getSizeChange()`, which I just multiply by the default text size to get my real text size.